# Drop Down List with WPF Menu Controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am looking for a way to add a drop down list in WPF to a menu. This used to be really easy in winforms and so I am expecting you experts to know just now to do it in WPF. Thanks.

Sorry if this is a bad question, it is late and I don't want to think.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is very easy to add any UIElement to any control, You can just add Combobox to a Menu control and create menu as bellow.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
        <Separator/>
        <ComboBox Width="85" Height="21.96" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Your image link seems to have broken. If you still have the original image, please reupload it to stack.imgur.

Answer (score 19):

While this is very easy to do as Jobi Joy has shown, I think it has horrible usability. The Menu control supports multiple levels of menu items and I would go down that route for UI consistency.